# Buttons/Labels not displayed when creating GUI inside actionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, render, actionlistener

==============

I am creating a small 2D game which consists of a 'Main Menu' GUI, and an 'In-game' GUI (which is used to render the graphics).

The Main Menu naturally has a "Start" button to create a game world and the In-Game GUI. All components work fine if you run them independently, but if "actionPerformed" in the action listener on the Start button is called, the In-Game GUI does not render all buttons/labels/scroll-pane properly, and doesn't apply the default close operation.

**Image**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKHiY.jpg

On the Left, the buttons are not rendered. On the Right, they are.

The difference between code to produce left/right images:

### -FOR LEFT IMAGE-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class BensGUI extends JFrame{

    public BensGUI()
    {
        final JFrame bensGUI = this;
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        mainPanel.add(start);

        //This GUI is simplified from the real Main Menu


        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                    Player p1 = new Player("player 1", new AntBrainParser().parseBrain("cleverbrain2.brain"));
                    Player p2 = new Player("player 2", new AntBrainParser().parseBrain("horseshoe.brain"));
                    Pos[][] ps = new MapParser().parseMap("5.world"); //The World class creates the in-game GUI inside its constructor
                    World w = new World(p1, p2, ps, 3427);
                  } 
        } );



        pane.add(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### -FOR RIGHT IMAGE-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class BensGUI extends JFrame{

    public BensGUI()
    {
        final JFrame bensGUI = this;
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        mainPanel.add(start);


        Player p1 = new Player("player 1", new AntBrainParser().parseBrain("cleverbrain2.brain"));
        Player p2 = new Player("player 2", new AntBrainParser().parseBrain("horseshoe.brain"));
        Pos[][] ps = new MapParser().parseMap("5.world");
        World w = new World(p1, p2, ps, 3427); //The World class creates the in-game GUI inside its constructor

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

                  } 
        } );

        //This GUI is simplified from the real Main Menu

        pane.add(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Please note, when the buttons do not display, you cannot close the window by clicking the "X" in the top right (*despite the setDefaultCloseOperation line being executed*). Resizing the window results in repainting 'glitches' (imgur.com/bOpCzGC). Buttons will not repaint or react when clicked/hovered-over.

- If I place a main method in the World class and run it without a Main Menu GUI of any form, it works fine.
- If I *bypass* the Main Menu by calling the World constructor (which calls the In-Game GUI constructor), before it has chance to be made visible, (as with "FOR RIGHT IMAGE")  it produces the Right image above.
- It appears as though all lines of code in the In-Game GUI are executed.
- The game does *actually* run when the buttons are not displayed. But you have no control over the scroll-pane, buttons, or labels.

I cannot see what is causing this problem, and have tried to find a work-around. Would anyone be able to assist me here? It would be greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards,

-Ben

## ALL CODE

Here is all the code which is causing the problem. I have included the constructors only (for now), as even just running *them* causes the issue.

### SimulationGUI (aka In-Game GUI)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SimulationGUI extends JFrame{


    Pos[][] position;//2D array of positions which contains all the info about the cells
    int imageXSize = 25;
    int imageYSize = 27;
    int imageXOffset = 21;
    int rowOffsetValue = (imageXOffset/2);
    int imageYOffset = 16;
    int curRound = 0;
    boolean isRendering = true;
    public boolean isActive = true;
    int antTrackerID = 50;

    JFrame simGUIFrame = this;


//  public static void main(String[] args)
//  {
//      System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","True");
//      MapParser mp = new MapParser();
//      SimulationGUI gui = new SimulationGUI("Some text", mp.parseMap("1.world"));
//      gui.setUpWorld();
//  }


    //GUI ELEMENTS
    JPanel groundCanvas;
    BufferedImage offscreen;
    BufferedImage background;
    Graphics2D offScrGfx;
    Graphics2D bckGrdGfx;

    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    //Graphics2D g2d = new Graphics2D();


    //A load of ant and food images
    BufferedImage antBLK_S;
    BufferedImage antBLK_SE;
    BufferedImage antBLK_E;
    BufferedImage antBLK_NE;
    BufferedImage antBLK_N;
    BufferedImage antBLK_NW;
    BufferedImage antBLK_W;
    BufferedImage antBLK_SW; 

    BufferedImage antBLKF_S;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_SE;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_E;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_NE;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_N;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_NW;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_W;
    BufferedImage antBLKF_SW; 


    BufferedImage antRED_S;
    BufferedImage antRED_SE;
    BufferedImage antRED_E;
    BufferedImage antRED_NE;
    BufferedImage antRED_N;
    BufferedImage antRED_NW;
    BufferedImage antRED_W;
    BufferedImage antRED_SW; 

    BufferedImage antREDF_S;
    BufferedImage antREDF_SE;
    BufferedImage antREDF_E;
    BufferedImage antREDF_NE;
    BufferedImage antREDF_N;
    BufferedImage antREDF_NW;
    BufferedImage antREDF_W;
    BufferedImage antREDF_SW; 


    BufferedImage food_5;
    BufferedImage food_4;
    BufferedImage food_3;
    BufferedImage food_2;
    BufferedImage food_1;

    BufferedImage antTrackCell;


    ImageIcon boxChecked = new ImageIcon("Images/Check Button checked.png");
    ImageIcon boxUnChecked = new ImageIcon("Images/Check Button unchecked.png");
    ImageIcon playButton = new ImageIcon("Images/Play Button.png");
    ImageIcon pausedButton = new ImageIcon("Images/Paused Button.png");
    ImageIcon restartIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/Restart Icon.png");
    ImageIcon quitIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/Quit Icon.png");
    ImageIcon foodIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/foodIcon.png");


    //Variables used in GUI
    JProgressBar progressBar;
    World world;
    JLabel roundCounter;
    String roundNum;
    JLabel redCount;
    JLabel blkCount;
    JLabel foodCount;
    JButton renderPause;
    JLabel redScore;
    JLabel blkScore;
    JLabel antTrackerLabel;
    JTextField antTrackerIDBox;





    //Parameters used by the World Class
    HashMap<Integer, Ant> antMap = new HashMap<Integer, Ant>();
    ArrayList<Pos> foodPosArray = new ArrayList<Pos>();



    public SimulationGUI(String title, Pos[][] positionArray, World w)
    {



        groundCanvas = new JPanel();

        redCount = new JLabel("Red Ants:   ######", boxUnChecked, JLabel.LEFT);
        blkCount = new JLabel("Black Ants: ######", boxUnChecked,  JLabel.LEFT);
        foodCount = new JLabel("Food: ######", foodIcon,  JLabel.LEFT);
        redScore = new JLabel("Red Score:  ######");
        blkScore = new JLabel("Blk Score:  ######");
        renderPause = new JButton("Render", boxChecked);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(groundCanvas);
        antTrackerLabel = new JLabel("Ant ID");
        antTrackerIDBox = new JTextField("20");

        this.world = w;
        this.position = positionArray;
        this.setTitle("Ant Simulation | "+title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        this.setLocation(400, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();


        //Graphics Setup
//      System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","True");

        //Canvas and JScrollPane

        groundCanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(imageXOffset*position.length + 10,imageYOffset*position.length + 10));
        offscreen = (BufferedImage) createImage(imageXOffset*position.length + 10,imageYOffset*position.length + 10);
        background = (BufferedImage) createImage(imageXOffset*position.length + 10,imageYOffset*position.length + 10);
        offScrGfx = (Graphics2D) offscreen.getGraphics();
        bckGrdGfx = (Graphics2D) background.getGraphics();


        scrollPane.add(groundCanvas);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,450));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(groundCanvas);




        ///////////////////////////


        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomMainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel topMainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel antTracker = new JPanel();

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        topMainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        antTracker.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton restartButton = new JButton("Restart", restartIcon);
        final JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause", playButton);
        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit", quitIcon);
        final JButton speedUp = new JButton("");
        final JButton slowDown = new JButton("");
        speedUp.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Images/speedUp.png"));
        slowDown.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Images/slowDown.png"));

//      progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, w.maxRounds);
//      progressBar.setValue(0);
//      progressBar.setStringPainted(true);


        roundCounter = new JLabel("Round: #######");


        //ACTION LISTENERS////////


        //Action listeners are commented out for now...

        //Add the buttons/bars/labels to their panels


        bottomMainPanel.add(roundCounter);
        bottomMainPanel.add(speedUp);
        bottomMainPanel.add(slowDown);
        bottomMainPanel.add(renderPause);
        bottomMainPanel.add(restartButton);
        bottomMainPanel.add(pauseButton);
        bottomMainPanel.add(quitButton);
        bottomPanel.add(bottomMainPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //bottomPanel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JPanel antTrackerContainer = new JPanel();

        antTrackerContainer.add(antTrackerLabel);
        antTrackerContainer.add(antTrackerIDBox);
        antTracker.add(antTrackerContainer, BorderLayout.WEST);


        antTrackerIDBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 20));


        topMainPanel.add(redCount);
        topMainPanel.add(redScore);
        topMainPanel.add(foodCount);
        topMainPanel.add(blkCount);
        topMainPanel.add(blkScore);
        topMainPanel.add(antTracker);


        middlePanel.add(scrollPane);



        topPanel.add(topMainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pane.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        this.pack();



    }
```

### World (created inside BensGUI actionListener *as above*)

```
World(Player player1, Player player2, Pos[][] positions, int initialSeed) {
        // initialise variables
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
        player1.setColour("red");
        player2.setColour("black");
        this.positions = positions;
        this.foodPositions = new ArrayList<Pos>();
        ants = new HashMap<Integer, Ant>();
        this.initialSeed = initialSeed;

        seed.add(new BigInteger("" + initialSeed)); // initial seed
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            seed.add(seed.get(i - 1).multiply(new BigInteger("22695477"))
                    .add(new BigInteger("1")));
        }

        generateAnts();
        System.out.println(ants.size());
        //In-Game GUI Setup:
        sim = new SimulationGUI("", positions, this);
        sim.setUpWorld();
        sim.pack();
        gameStart();
    }
```

It's worth noting:

- For testing purposes, I have temporarily commented-out the update-related methods in the World class which would cause the JPanel *groundCanvas* to be repainted on every frame of the game. When I do this, it causes (A.) to happen (*see image below*).
- When I allow the World class to update the *groundCanvas*, it results in (B.)
- **Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Goq.png

*I've added all the code which is necessary to this issue now*

Comment: So basically the code is the same, the only difference is the block in the middle is moved outside the actionPerformed method ?

Comment: That's correct. It means that I cannot have a Main Menu GUI of any description which will require the user to click "Start" when they want to load the In-Game GUI.

Comment: Can you comment the block of code moved (from Player p1 to World w) and tell me if the button appears ?

Comment: If I comment out the code creating the World object w, the In-Game GUI is not created, as the World object's constructor contains code which creates a new In-Game GUI object. So in other words, nothing, other than the displaying of BensGUI, would happen.

Comment: Btw where is the start button in the images ?

Comment: The images show the In-Game GUI. The code snippet I provided show the (_simplified_) Main Menu.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are omitting many essential details, such as layouts of these panels. You may need to call `pack()` inside `addActionListener` to repack the frame. Maybe also revalidate the panels.

Comment: The Layouts I have used are BorderLayout, GridLayout, and the default layout. I tried pack() and revalidating the panels as suggested, but this did not solve the problem. I wonder if it might be connected with the JScrollPane? If I comment out everything which references the JScrollPane, it _seems_ to render the buttons correctly, but throws an error: (Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException) on the line: groundCanvas.getGraphics().drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, groundCanvas); (_groundCanvas is a JPanel, and offscreen is a BufferedImage BTW)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an ***[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).***

Comment: Thank you - I have added in the code which is causing the problems. The SimulationGUI class is referred to as "_In-Game GUI_" in my description above.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have edited in the code causing the problem, as requested